# How to surpass location enabler dialogue in UI testing Espresso android?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-espresso

I am using Espresso for UI testing android. I wanted to run a test with location off in the settings and I got stuck with the location enabler dialogue as it fails other test. I have mentioned my observations and what I have tried so far

- Used UiAutomator, it works only on single test case but it fails on
  complete run of test suite.
- Used Grant permission rule, it gave permission but the dialogue still
  exists.
- Used Roboelectric, it had no effect on the problem.
- Used Shadow operation, it had no effect on the problem.

I have also attached a sample image of the location dialogue.
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently I'm using grantPerms method which should be added to all test classes (all = test-classes which require access to android permissions) so I'm just call it at the right time (if app need perms).

Here is scheme:

```
     public class MyClass {
        // Rules etc.

        @Test
        public void myTestWithPerms() {
        // click view, if it's need permissions to camera etc., just call
        grantPerms(); //calling inner grantPerms method

        // Another code, if you need access to gallery now
         grantPerms(); //calling inner grantPerms method

        // Some test code
        }

        private void grantPerms(){
        // grantPermsCode
        }
}
```

Or do you mean something specific?

---

**Update**
I see, so I will show an example how I have resolved it on my side, for me this is good solution.

- **example:** imagine that you have some app which interact with phone contacts (1-st tap "Contact btn" in your app should cause raise of android permissions alert "Deny/Allow" btns)
- so currently your test will have a **line-wise structure** (access activity/screen -> check presence of UI component by certain params (title, ID, package name etc...) -> click on this component)
- **NOW after first tap** you should perform android permissions alert (YOU know after which action (tap etc.) this alert suppose to be shown)
- so YOU just **need to create a inner private method inside your test** class (which currently require access to android permissions) scheme was added above

  ---

  **UPDATE2:** generally you can't turn ON GPS services programmatically, this is not allowed since android v.4.2, so generally it's better to turn ON GPS services manually before test was started, but take a look at this

  solution, may be this is what you want:

  ```
      public class MyTestClass {

              // Rules etc.

          @Test
          public void myTestWithTurnOnGPS() {
              // once access the map check alert presence
              tapTurnOnGpsBtn(); //call inner **tapTurnOnGpsBtn** method
          }

          private void tapTurnOnGpsBtn() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {

              UiObject allowGpsBtn = device.findObject(new UiSelector()
                                                            .className("android.widget.Button").packageName("com.google.android.gms")
                                                            .resourceId("android:id/button1")
                                                            .clickable(true).checkable(false));
              device.pressDelete(); // just in case to turn ON blur screen (not a wake up) for some devices like HTC and some other
              if (allowGpsBtn.exists() && allowGpsBtn.isEnabled()) {
                  do {
                      allowGpsBtn.click();
                  } while (allowGpsBtn.exists());
              }
         }
  ```

  }

So this method should be call in all places IN YOUR APP which suppose to raise GPS alert ()

Comment: I mean providing real time permission pop-up that crashes the test for that solution?

Comment: So if I'm not wrong and understood you correctly
- you have separate test-class which allow permissions for android 6+ (which is based on UIautomator) AND this separate test-class work good
- next, when you running test-suite which includes grant permissions test-class, you are getting only requerable permissions on app start

BUT you want to allow all of them right on the app start?

Comment: Yeah its almost same but the issue is it runs perfectly fine if I run single file test. If the run the whole UI file then the test crashes as the pop-up is blocking the test.

Comment: I'm have edited my comment, generally you should call inner grant perms method (which allow android permissions) after each action which suppose to raise android permissions alert.

Do you need code sample for grant permissions method which allow permissions and usage sample?

Comment: Yeah sure please give a sample so that I might get an idea of how to approach for the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Yeah please give a sample so that I might get an idea of how to approach for the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, I'm a little bit miss your question, I have added example, is it clear for your?

1) **inner private method** (turnOnGPS method) should be called in places where alert suppose to appear.
2) this method should be included in all your test classes (which suppose to have such kind of GPS alert).

Comment: In code missing next line, just add it before  UiObject allowGpsBtn  **UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());**

Comment: Sure, perhaps I have missed something in code or in idea, that's better to know.

Comment: I tried your solution, it had no effect on the location pop-up, it failed again.

Comment: If it's possible let me know about these 3 items:
- It's crash only in the test-suite?
- Can you provide scenario of what you are going to do by your suite + where did you tried to turn ON the GPS services (sample what I would like to see: **1-test** going to login the app, **2-test** trying to turn ON GPS via alert, **3-test** navigating on the map etc... )?

Comment: On start of the test class,  the Pop-up arises then I will call the function on the @Before . 2-test trying to turn ON GPS via alert

Comment: It would not work, you should call gpsOn method right in the test implementation, not in set up activity section.
**Rule**
put here your activity test rule.
**Before**
set up here your activity instrumentation.
**After**
tear down / finish activities.
**Test**
assert your activity.
assert presence of OK btn on the alert (by ID, package name or index etc.).
ONLY now call **tapTurnOnGpsBtn()** to click on OK = to turn ON GPS.
Then do what you need, proceed test etc.

Comment: Did you follow last comment?

Comment: Yeah I have access

Comment: Okay, I just want to know how you are currently create your test classes. 
Can your share test-class where you are currently implement it.

Just in case, using grey-box testing and UiAutomator, I have created separate project (and test-class in it) for Google Maps (preconditions: launch with already logged in user + skipped tutorial + already granted android perms + **turned OFF gps** = this is entry point) and everything looks good. 
I can share exact code example if you provide your own :)

Comment: It worked, Nothing wrong with your code. The problem was on my code, after refactoring It got passed. Thanks Man.

Comment: But anything in Espresso that can do the job?