# Espresso doesn't perform click on dialog

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, ui-testing, android-gps

Espresso doesn't perform click on a Dialog for enabling GPS generated on this code:

```
rae.startResolutionForResult(
  context,
  Constants.GPS_REQUEST
)
```

I haven't created this dialog so is not part of my "screen" nor "app", it's generated by the system or request to solve the gps resolution.

So I check if gps is enabled, if isn't then this is my line of code to press it:

`onView(withText("OK")).perform(click())`

But it doesn't work since it looks like Espresso keeps waiting for something to happen and then it crashes alone:
`androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?`

It doesn't matter if i set random words on the `withText("Random words sjdj")` it won't work because "it's waiting"

I thought about performing a click on coordinates but that looks like a flakky test because of the height and width and might not be accurate at all (I'm saying it from ignorance) and probably won't work because espresso is waiting.

**Edit 1:**

If I wait until test stops by itself it throws me the next error:

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
```

I guess Activity is onPause or something like that and is waiting for the dialog resolution?

But if i set the location good, test works as it should

What can I do to accept/cancel this dialog?

I don't want to be manually checking if location is on. I want to test that everything works as it should.

Here's an image of the actual screen

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the button by it's ID? These system dialogs have the ID of button1 and button2, so it'd be something like `onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click())`

Comment: Hi @agoff thank you for your reply!! But sadly couldn't make it work since it keeps waiting and I found that if I wait for too long it throws me the next error:
```androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?```

Which I guess is because the activity is onPause so Espresso is waiting for it to resume? What do you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

Found someone who had the same problem as me and the solution was to use an UiAutomator which use the UI of the Device! which Espresso can't reach!

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455867/9420348)